# Why does Visual Studio create another *.appx inside a folder Dependecies

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-8.1, package

I created a new App Package for my 8.1 phone and I see a separate
*.appx (Phone.WinJS.2.1.appx) inside a folder "Dependecies".
Do I need this file to deploy my App and if not - can somebody explain why it was created, please?

Comment: as the names says, your app depends on this JavaScript library, so deploy this dependency appx before installing the appx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acutally, "Dependencies" folder contains other packages. It simply declares other packages that a package depends on to complete its software/application.

As per MSDN:

> Dependencies must be explicitly defined. If a dependency cannot be
>   resolved, deployment of the package fails. By default, a package
>   cannot take a dependency on another package if the dependency package
>   is not declared to be a framework package.

Example from MSDN

```
<Dependencies>
    <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.WinJS.1.0"
      Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
      MinVersion="1.0.0.0"/>    
</Dependencies>
```

Check app package requirement details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/app-package-requirements) and dependencies [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appxmanifestschema/element-dependencies).